# "You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction" when createEntityManagerFactory called

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to implement multi-tenancy by separating schemas in my application. In doing this, I have a `Tenant` entity which contains a `String schemaName`, and I have a `Singleton` `Startup` EJB which creates a map of `EntityManagerFactory`'s on startup; one factory assigned to each `Tenant`.

Here is my EJB:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class TenantManagementServiceImpl implements TenantManagementService {

    private Map<Tenant, EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactoryMap;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        buildEntityManagerFactories();
    }

    private List<Tenant> getAllTenants() {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Tenant.getAll", Tenant.class).getResultList();
    }

    private void buildEntityManagerFactories() {
        entityManagerFactoryMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Tenant tenant : getAllTenants()) {
            Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", tenant.getSchemaName());
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyApp", properties);
            entityManagerFactoryMap.putIfAbsent(tenant, entityManagerFactory);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(Tenant tenant) {
        return entityManagerFactoryMap.get(tenant);
    }

}
```

And the `NamedQuery` being used:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Tenant.getAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Tenant t")
```

Unfortunately, on startup, I receive this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.TenantManagementServiceImpl.START" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.TenantManagementServiceImpl.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyApp] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyApp] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to open JDBC connection for schema management target
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031017: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction"}}
```

The error takes place on this line:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyApp", properties);
```

I am using [this guide](https://www.tomas-dvorak.cz/posts/jpa-multitenancy/) as a reference. I don't understand why I am receiving this error. I am using WildFly 10. What is going wrong, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default transaction behavior of an EJB is container-managed, which means transaction lifecycle is managed by ejb container of the application server. You need to set it as bean-managed by annotating your ejb class like:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TenantManagementServiceImpl implements TenantManagementService {


}
```

Comment: And why does it require bean transactions to make a query in a `@Startup
@Singleton` ?